# Azure YAML pipeline variables not showing when clicking on run pipeline

Tags: variables, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a yml pipeline that is triggered by a merge to our develop branch. This uses a PowerShell script that check what has changed in the merge and creates a list of services that should be built and deployed. in the PowerShell I have added variable for manual triggers called `BuildQueueManual`.  my issue is not with the yml code itself but the pipeline.

With the yml I have added this value as a global variable:

```
variables:
    BuildQueueManual: 

resources:
- repo: self

pool:
  name: Windows

stages:
- stage: Prerequisites
  jobs:
  - job: GetBuildQueue
    steps:
```

However, this variable doesn't appear when I run the pipeline. As you can see from the screenshot below, it says it has no defined variables:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ross, is there any update for this issue? Does answer below helps to resolve this issue?Please check it and feel free to let me know if the issue persists :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#allow-at-queue-time

> You can choose which variables are allowed to be set at queue time and
>   which are fixed by the pipeline author. If a variable appears in the
>   variables block of a YAML file, it is fixed and cannot be overridden
>   at queue time. To allow a variable to be set at queue time, make sure
>   it doesn't appear in the variables block of a pipeline or job. You can
>   set a default value in the editor, and that value can be overridden by
>   the person queuing the pipeline.